# VirtualBox Java API - Get IP Address of VM in VirtualBox

Tags: java, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ip-address

I have question related to getting IP address, I referred to few online resources and some answers already but I was not able to still fix it,
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=65910 - link that most matched with my question.

Configuration : 

`Host Machine : Windows 8
Guest : Slitaz 4.0
VirtualBox : 4.3.24
VirtualBox Java API : 4.3
Adapter in VM : Host Only Adapter
Slitaz Guest Additions are also installed.`

I have created a Java program using VirtualBox API and I can basically connect, clone and start a VM in VirtualBox. But what I was not able to do is get the IP address of machine. (Why I need IP is because I want to SSH into that machine, using JSCH java library and execute some processes)

This is what I tried so far,

Based on the link mentioned above,

```
 machine.getGuestPropertyValue("/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/<nicid>/V4/IP") - returns empty result
 machine.getGuestPropertyValue("/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/Count") - returns empty result
 machine.getGuestPropertyValue("/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/<nicid>/MAC") - return empty result
 machine.getGuestPropertyValue("/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release") - this gives me release version of linux - which is ok
```

I tried this one more thing, how many properties are exactly available

```
 org.virtualbox_4_3.Holder<List<String>> tempList = new Holder<List<String>>();
 org.virtualbox_4_3.Holder<List<String>> tempList1 = new Holder<List<String>>();
 Holder<List<Long>> tempList2 = new Holder<List<Long>>();
 org.virtualbox_4_3.Holder<List<String>> tempList3 = new Holder<List<String>>();
 machine.enumerateGuestProperties("",tempList, tempList1,tempList2,tempList3);
```

Now in templist, I get name of all properties available and in tempList1 it's values.

`[/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product, /VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID, /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVerExt, /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Vbgl/Video/SavedMode, /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Version, /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt, /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision, /VirtualBox/HostGuest/SysprepExec, /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Vbgl/Video/0, /VirtualBox/HostGuest/SysprepArgs, /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version, /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxRev, /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVer, /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release, /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/HostVerLastChecked]`

That is the reason, I think this works

`machine.getGuestPropertyValue("/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release") - this gives me release version of linux - which is ok`

But there is no property related to IP. Also I am not sure what exactly here is nicid and how to get this using API, is it mac address of adapter in VM, or something else.

`machine.getGuestPropertyValue("/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/<nicid>/V4/IP")`

Can somebody please help me out here or guide in appropriate direction.

Comment: See https://github.com/enexusde/vboxjws/wiki/Code-Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to virtual box forum, for solving the issue here is the link
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=66788&sid=bc4d34a5ad65fe3ff5006f91c8690817

But to summarize the solution,

1. It was made sure that guest additions on slitaz are compatible (correct versions) with the one matching with virtual box version.
2. Problem was `VBoxService` was not started automatically during the boot process of `Slitaz`.
3. So `etc/rcS.conf` file was edited to add extra program in LOAD_MODULES 
   `.............. /usr/sbin/VBoxService` (use `which VBoxService` to get the path for service)
4. Now when Slitaz was restarted, this process was running and 
   `vboxmanage guestproperty enumerate '<vmname>'` listed all the configuration
5. and one intereseted was,
   `Name: /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP, value: 192.168.56.101, timestamp: 1427467107101664501, flags:`

Hope it helps somebody !!!